# Flex Regex printing "()" for the output

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex

i am writing flex, i have a problem when i write as a input 00:50, i would like to have as a output: 1 tTIME (00:50), but with my code i am having this output: 1 tTIME 00:50)

My line is here. Where is my problem? Thanks in advance.

```
 ^([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3])[:]([0-5][0-9])$ {
    yytext[yyleng-yyleng-1]='(';yytext[yyleng]=')';
    printf("%d tTIME %s \n ", linecounter,yytext);
}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to mess around with the contents of `yytext,`, and the intended meaning of `yytext[yyleng-yyleng-1]` escapes me entirely.

Comment: i was trying to do yytext[-1] this was the last attempt i was trying to do, i used to make yytext[0] ,but it did not work. Do you have any suggestion for that problem can cover tTIME (00:50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of being obvious, if you want to printf a string with parentheses around it, you should printf a string with parentheses around it:

```
printf("%d tTIME (%s) \n ", linecounter, yytext);
```

There is no need to modify the string to do that.

The characters pointed to by `yytext` do not belong to you. If you need a copy of the string for some reason, you need to create yourself a copy, and you are free to add more characters while you do that. For example:

```
char* pstring = malloc(yyleng + 3); /* Room for the parentheses and NUL */
sprintf(pstring, "(%s)", yytext);
```

For anything even slightly more complicated, you would want to use `snprintf` or, even better if you have it, `asprintf`.

<opinion>This question has little to do with `flex`. Flex is a really useful tool, but it is not a substitute for understanding how to use C to do string manipulation.</opinion>